# Fabric node sdk:Failed to submit transaction: Error: DiscoveryService: gocc error: failed constructing descriptor for chaincodes:<name:"gocc" >

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

```
{
    "name": "first-network-fbr",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "tls":{
            "cert":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nJWPZxTlDAiBcqlR0cnls9AAQsd5dOWj3Ln3EsInYJpUJ9jRadNWv4w==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",
            "key":"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgr7GQkNVuea+4ngTV\nXGzTNEdWg8GclqjL74NdlqNxXVShRANCAAR46kyroNQiDEOMgm9XwmvLUIlbP2df\nwyx/0ziXUbQbiV1VYCo5IeeGTflPJuVmeInCLEE6s5kbvH86zea2FSw0\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
        },
        "organization": "Fbr",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Fbr": {
            "mspid": "FbrMSP",
            "peers": [
                "peer1.fbr.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.fbr.com"
            ]
        }
    },
    "peers": {
    "peer1.fbr.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:10051",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nJWPZxTlDAiBcqlR0cnls9AAQsd5dOWj3Ln3EsInYJpUJ9jRadNWv4w==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.fbr.com",
                "hostnameOverride": "peer1.fbr.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.fbr.com": {
            "url": "https://localhost:7054",
            "caName": "ca.fbr.com",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nJWPZxTlDAiBcqlR0cnls9AAQsd5dOWj3Ln3EsInYJpUJ9jRadNWv4w==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            },
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above is my connection profile.

```
const { Gateway, Wallets } = require('fabric-network');
const path = require('path');
const helper=require('./helper');
// Set connection options
const ccpPath = helper.getCCP("fbr");


async function invoke() {
  const walletPath = await helper.getWalletPath("fbr") //.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
  const wallet = await Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletPath);
  const gatewayOptions = {
  wallet,
  identity: 'Fbradmin',
  discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true },
  eventHandlerOptions:{
    strategy:null
  }
};
  try {
    // Connect to gateway using connection profile and wallet
    const gateway = new Gateway();
    await gateway.connect(ccpPath, gatewayOptions);

    // Get network and contract objects
    const network = await gateway.getNetwork('automobilechannel');
    const contract = network.getContract('gocc');
    console.log(contract);
    // Submit transaction to chaincode
    // const result =await contract.submitTransaction("transfer", "3520299610969", "1234", "100","Dar");
    let txn=contract.createTransaction("transfer");
    console.log(txn.getName());
    console.log(txn.getTransactionId());
    let result=await txn.submit("3520299610969", "1234", "100","Dar");
    console.log('Transaction has been submitted',String(result));
    gateway.disconnect();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to submit transaction: ${error}`);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

invoke();
```

above is my nodejs testing file.

2023-05-01T07:17:13.814Z - error: [DiscoveryResultsProcessor]: parseDiscoveryResults[gocc] - Channel:automobilechannel received discovery error:failed constructing descriptor for chaincodes:<name:"gocc" >

Failed to submit transaction: Error: DiscoveryService: gocc error: failed constructing descriptor for chaincodes:<name:"gocc" >

I am getting this error .

most of you will say you don't have gocc installed but I have already queried against this gocc contract id and its working fine.

Comment: Hello. Have you had any luck with this? I am facing the same issue. Chaincode properly installed, approved and committed in the channel, I am able to invoke from the cli but from the SDK this error.